# How can I use variables that are defined in the html file in typescript?

Tags: html, typescript, spring-mvc

I use spring MVC to pass data from java to javascript and start a webcomponent. To grab the variables with javascript I had this line in the html file:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    const data = /*[[${data}]]*/ '';
</script>
```

This worked great! I was able to use the variable in every .js file I added to the html. But now I switched to Typescript and its not compiling because I doesnt see the variable. Is there a way around this?

Btw.: The variable is a rather complex object with subobjects and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare it in a `.d.ts` file:

```
declare const data: DataInterface;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html